# Where can I find fireproof caulk backer?

Tags: fireplace, caulking

A while back I asked [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4001/sealing-large-gap-around-my-fireplace-fireproof-diy-and-effective-at-prevent) and got a lot of great responses.

I've been able to locate fireblock caulk, but one thing I didn't think of is the backer. I need some kind of fireblock/fireproof caulk backer for the gap in my fireplace's molding. The only caulk backer at Home Depot I've found is the polyethelyne backer. Something like [this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=caulk++backer&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=2835729355509480852&sa=X&ei=QRFsTfyWNZDmsQO_1KGTBA&ved=0CBgQ8wIwAA#).

All of this stuff explicitly says to not expose it to heat, and that it's highly flamable, but I need something that will be fireproof.

What should I be using for caulk backer in an area highly sensitive to heat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Furnace cement will work fine, you can also use, thinset, any setting type drywall mix, or High temp High density spun insulation. They all will work good as a caulk backer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try and fill the majority of the gap with furnace cement, allow it to harden, and then seal the remainder with the caulk.